# Why does browser always converts $ to %24?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

While entering url with $ at browser address bar it automatically converts the $ to %24 ,why cant the browser send the url as it is?

For e.g

perform a search of **$** in superuser address bar ,it automatically converts to superuser.com/search?q=%24 .ie  superuser.com at browser address bar it automatically converts the url to %24

Any reason behind the browser displaying it as encoded value?why can't browser display as it is the url?

While exploring further it always converts automatically all of the special characters ,any reason behind this kind of encoding?

Comment: [so] duplicate [Why browsers encode url in this form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4530173)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because some characters have special meanings.
>
> For instance, in a query string, the ampersand (&) is used as a
>   separator between key-value pairs. If you were to put an ampersand
>   into one of those values, it would look like the separator between the
>   end of a value and the beginning of the next key. So for special
>   characters like this, we use percent encoding so that we can be sure
>   that the data is unambiguously encoded. [[Ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899619/1793718)

Its simply URL encoding and since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

See here the list of URL encoding characters. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) and [ASCII encoding reference](http://ascii.cl/url-encoding.htm)